# SQL Server Select field not recognized in VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that used to return a field with a value to a VBA application. But all of a sudden, the field stopped being recognized by the VBA application. The message I get is : Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal. When I run directly in SQL Server, it returns the value.

I have other similar stored procedures that work fine with the same application. Any clue why this is happening? 
It was working earlier today. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's a SQL Error.  Either `ADOCmd` is not properly declared, or there is no parameter called `Erruer`.  (But you posted 1.5 SQL squeries and 0.5 procedures so it's hard to tell what's going on.) **More about the [`Parameters` Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado)** here.

Comment: The problem is not with the parameter but with the field Nb_Rec in my SELECT COUNT() which returns the number of records in a table.

Comment: A minute ago it was the previous line giving the error?  that's a pretty big difference.  Can you please most more information (**See "[MCVE]") and [edit] to clarify the question.  And if you know which field is creating the error, perhaps you should be including information & sample data from the relevant field.  What relevance is the SQL in the top half of the image id the problem field isn't even listed?

Comment: What value does the query return when you run it in SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

It was never reaching the `SELECT COUNT` because there was a string to date conversion error.